# How can we attract Quora users from Quora topics related to Patents?

Tags: discussion

I would love to see this SE burgeon! How can we invite or enthrall Quora users from these Quora topics?

[Patents](https://www.quora.com/topic/Patents) has 282.4K followers.

[Patent Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Patent-Law) has 262.2K followers.

[Software Patents](https://www.quora.com/topic/Software-Patents) 40.8K.

[Patent Litigation](https://www.quora.com/topic/Patent-Litigation) 33.1K.

[United States Patent and Trademark Office](https://www.quora.com/topic/United-States-Patent-and-Trademark-Office) 31.1K.

[Patent Trolls](https://www.quora.com/topic/Patent-Trolls). 23.8K.

Answer (score 0):

One effective way could be by adding links to this SE in the comments and the answers posted on Quora. One can use the https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/referrals to quantify how many visitors followed such links.

Note that Quora uses some illegal methods to attract more users:
[Quora users (bots?) are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342516/178179).